# Can I use Youtube dataAPI Version 3 on zend framework 2.X version

Tags: zend-framework2, youtube-data-api

Not able to find any details on the net on whether Zend framework 2.X supports youtube dataAPI 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

ZF2 doesn't support YouTube like ZF1. However there is a module https://github.com/snapshotpl/ZfSnapGoogle to using Google APIs.